# How to upload single image with two dimensional Dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire, swift5

My parameters are -

> {"data":{"uid":
> "90a3d021-c072-4c51-a257-cca414c1099e","encrypted":false, "user_type":
> "2"},"encoded_data":"yes"}

And here is my code -

```
 let url =  "\(Config.serverBaseUrl)\(apiType.rawValue)\(serviceType.rawValue)"
  
        let headers = [
        "Authorization": "Token \(UtilityClass().getLoginDetail()?.data?.token ?? "")"]

          Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
                      for (key, value) in parameter {
                          multipartFormData.append("\(value)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key as String)
                      }

                          multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "profile_image", fileName: "image.png", mimeType: "image/png")
                      
                  }, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), to: url, method: .post, headers: headers) { (result) in
                      switch result{
                      case .success(let upload, _, _):
                          upload.responseJSON { response in
                              print("Succesfully uploaded  = \(response)")
                              if let err = response.error{

                                  print(err)
                                  return
                              }

                          }
                      case .failure(let error):
                          print("Error in upload: \(error.localizedDescription)")

                      }
                  }
```

Comment: i don't think it's regarding swift 5 because alamofire call in it like `AF` requests

Comment: And how is supposed to look like your request according to your api spec?

Comment: @jatinfl Yes this is not Swift 5 code. I am stuck in this since last 2 days. please help if you know

Comment: when I hit api. I am getting this error -

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0."

Comment: did you try this in postman?

Comment: @jatinfl yes api is working in postman as well as in android. I am appending the parameters then they are not appending properly so the error is coming. as you can see parameters have two dictionary. This code is working for one dictionary parameter like ---
{"uid": "90a3d021-c072-4c51-a257-cca414c1099e","encrypted":false, "user_type": "2"}

please help me out.

Comment: as i know `3840` corrupted propertylist errorso check here `upload.responseJSON {`